# "wxPython in Action" book program works direct but not from notepad++

Tags: python, wxpython

Im following the book "wxPython in Action"

and it gives the example below

when I run the program from my "notepad++" I get a pile of errors (see bottom) however when I run the program direct by double clicking it works!

- just tried "Idle" - it works!

Any points please!

Cheers

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
"""Hello, wxPython! program.""" 
import wx 
class Frame(wx.Frame): 
    """Frame class that displays an image.""" 
    def __init__(self, image, parent=None, id=-1, 
                pos=wx.DefaultPosition, 
                title='Hello, wxPython!'): 
        """Create a Frame instance and display image.""" 
        temp = image.ConvertToBitmap() 
        size = temp.GetWidth(), temp.GetHeight() 
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, pos, size) 
        self.bmp = wx.StaticBitmap(parent=self, bitmap=temp) 
class App(wx.App): 
    """Application class.""" 
    def OnInit(self): 
        image = wx.Image('wxPython.jpg', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_JPEG) 
        self.frame = Frame(image) 
        self.frame.Show() 
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame) 
        return True 
def main(): 
    app = App() 
    app.MainLoop() 
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    main()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Z:\Programming\Python2.7\temp.py", line 26, in <module>
    main()
  File "Z:\Programming\Python 2.7\temp.py", line 23, in main
    app = App()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-3.0-msw\wx\_core.py", line 8631, in __init__
    self._BootstrapApp()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-3.0-msw\wx\_core.py", line 8196, in _BootstrapApp
    return _core_.PyApp__BootstrapApp(*args, **kwargs)
  File "Z:\Programming\Python 2.7\temp.py", line 18, in OnInit
    self.frame = Frame(image)
  File "Z:\Programming\Python 2.7\temp.py", line 10, in __init__
    temp = image.ConvertToBitmap()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-3.0-msw\wx\_core.py", line 3646, in ConvertToBitmap
    return _core_.Image_ConvertToBitmap(*args, **kwargs)
wx._core.PyAssertionError: C++ assertion "image.IsOk()" failed at ..\..\src\msw\bitmap.cpp(820) in wxBitmap::CreateFromImage(): invalid image
```

Comment: How are you executing the code from notepad++?

Comment: Wow - that took some working out, Id set it up ages ago and had forgotten... F5 run then C:\Python27\python.exe -i "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cheers PSS the clue I needed

If I change the line

```
image = wx.Image('//Server/users/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/wxPython.jpg', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_JPEG)
```

then it works!

I ASSuME its something to do with my windows desktop accessing my Ubuntu/Linux Server!

I've had trouble with those pesky backslashes and forward slashes before! :(

I've had to use "os" to overcome

```
Basepathfile = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
FileName = 'wxPython.jpg'
PrelimPathFile = os.path.join(Basepathfile, FileName )
PathFile = os.path.normpath(PrelimPathFile)
```

hence new program - BUT IT DOESN'T ANSWER WHY!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
"""Hello, wxPython! program.""" 
import wx 
import os

class Frame(wx.Frame): 
    """Frame class that displays an image.""" 
    def __init__(self, image, parent=None, id=-1, 
                pos=wx.DefaultPosition, 
                title='Hello, wxPython!'): 
        """Create a Frame instance and display image.""" 
        temp = image.ConvertToBitmap() 
        size = temp.GetWidth(), temp.GetHeight() 
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, pos, size) 
        self.bmp = wx.StaticBitmap(parent=self, bitmap=temp) 
class App(wx.App): 
    """Application class.""" 
    def OnInit(self): 
        Basepathfile = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        FileName = 'wxPython.jpg'
        PrelimPathFile = os.path.join(Basepathfile, FileName )
        PathFile = os.path.normpath(PrelimPathFile)
        image = wx.Image(PathFile, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_JPEG) 
        self.frame = Frame(image) 
        self.frame.Show() 
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame) 
        return True 
def main(): 
    app = App() 
    app.MainLoop() 
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    main()
```

Comment: Why?  Probably because when you ran the original program from the command line your current working directory was the same place where the image file was located, so it didn't need an absolute path name to find it.  When Notepadd++ ran it the CWD was likely somepace else, so it needed help to find the file.

Comment: Cheers but no! both files have always been in the same "working directory" - just done a test - copied both original files (program / image) to my desktop, and tried to run via notepad -this takes out the linux / windows mix - still fails!

Comment: @FloggedHorse Good that you found a solution by yourself. It would be nice if you could accept your answer by clicking on the tick mark on the left side, this will let other users know that this question is solved.

Comment: The location of the .py file is not neccessarily the CWD.  Try adding `import os; print os.getcwd()` someplace to be sure what it is.

Comment: Pss I would have ticked the pss - but as far as "stackoveflow" are concerned I'm to lowest of the low! I have had wait 2 days! :(

Comment: Ah ah Cheers RobinDunn 'import os; print os.getcwd()' = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++' ... so is there a way to get the CWD to be the place where the program is?