# wxPython 3.0.2.0 assertion error and output truncated

Tags: wxpython

I installed wxPython 3.0.2.0 and tested it with a simple "hello world". I got the follow error when calling `wx.frame`

```
$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, May 28 2015, 17:39:01) 
[GCC Intel(R) C++ gcc 4.8 mode] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import wx
>>> app = wx.App()
>>> frame = wx.Frame(None, title="Hello World")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   File "/scratch/wxPython/wxPython/wx/_windows.py", line 580, in __init__
    _windows_.Frame_swiginit(self,_windows_.new_Frame(*args, **kwargs))
wx._core.PyAssertionError: C++ assertion "Assert failure" failed at /scratch/wxPython/src/common/strc
```

The last line of the assertion error message was truncated. So I don't know the exact error message. My first question is how to show the entire error message, as in this post here:

["wxPython in Action" book program works direct but not from notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23710761/wxpython-in-action-book-program-works-direct-but-not-from-notepad)

Update on 01/09/2016: Managed to get the exact error message (without resolving the message being truncated problem). The error is `trying to encode undefined Unicode character` and happens in file wxpythonroot/src/common/strconv.cpp line 1208.

Update on 01/12/2016: Tried to build wxPython 2.8.12.1 and it works. This is the version provided in most Linux repositories.

Comment: FWIW: I am using Python 2.7.11 and wxPython 3.0.2.0 and those three lines work without issues.

Comment: @wil93 Since wxPython is a wrapper of wxWidgets, do I need to install wxWidgets first?

Comment: How did you install wxPython? Depending on the installation method, you may already have everything you need (e.g. I used `pacman -S wxpython` on ArchLinux, and that automatically pulled `wxgtk` as a dependency, which is wxWidgets from what I understand)

Comment: @wil93 I installed wxPython from source with `./build-wxpython.py`. My OS is CentOS 6 and I don't think I have wxgtk originally. I installed wxWidgets from source and set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH for it, but still got the same error. Seems wxPython is not well integrated with wxWidgets.

Comment: From the user guide, it seems `./build-wxpython.py` will build wxWidgets as well `http://wxpython.org/builddoc.php`

Comment: I am pretty sure `./build-wxpython.py` also installed wxWidgets.

Comment: Maybe this can be useful? http://superuser.com/questions/918304/how-to-install-wxpython-on-centos-6-5-python-2-7 I'm not sure

Comment: @wil93 Although I still don't know why the error message is truncated, I managed to find where the assertion failure occurs. It complains about `trying to encode undefined Unicode character`.  I will resolve that issue first. If every effort fails, I will then try installing from repository. Thanks.